# HTML Table with pagination and filter

Tags: javascript, html

I have JSON response from server stored in variable. I need to show data from response in HTML Table with sorting, pagination and filter. How can I make this job without 3rd party extensions/framework on plain JS?

p.s. I'm junior developer and looking for simple solution (code/algorithm).

Comment: This question is [off topic/too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Please read the [help]

Answer (score -1):

If you really want a simple and fast solution you better use datatables jquery plugin: https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables or you'll need to build something similar from scratch.

> DataTables is a table enhancing plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library, adding sorting, paging and filtering abilities to plain HTML tables with minimal effort. To meet this goal, DataTables is developed with two distinct groups of users in mind:
>
> You the developers using DataTables. For developers DataTables provides a wide array of options for how data should be obtained, displayed and acted upon, along with an extensive API for accessing and manipulating the table.
>
> End users. For those using the interface DataTables presents, actions to get the most from the information contained in tables, such as sorting and filtering, along with paging and scrolling of the data in table, are easy to use, intuitive and fast.

Comment: I need solution without 3rd party extensions. And I well known aboout jQuery DataTables....